# Verify that a set is $\sigma$-weakly dense in a von Neumann algebra

Tags: operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

[image]

The above lemma is from Takesaki's book (Vol 2, Chapter VIII).
I have two questions.

1.How to conclude that $e_nm_{\varphi}e_n$ is $\sigma$-weakly dense in $e_nMe_n$?

From Lemma 2.4, we only know that $m_{\varphi}$ is a $M_a^{\varphi}$-bimodule.

2.How to prove that $\cup e_nMe_n$ is $\sigma$-weakly dense in $M$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The question is why $m_\varphi$ is dense in $M$.

The assumption is that $\varphi$ is fns. Being semifinite, there exists projections $\{p_j\}$ with $\varphi(p_j)<\infty$ for all $j$ and $p_j\to 1$ weakly. Then $p_j\in m_\varphi$ for all $j$. As $m_\varphi$ is an $M_a^\varphi$-module, given $y\in M_a^\varphi$ we have $a=\lim p_ja\in \overline{m_\varphi}$. As $M_a^\varphi$ is dense in $M$ (Lemma 2.3), we get that
$$
\overline{m_\varphi}=\overline{M_a^\varphi}=M. 
$$

2. $e_n\nearrow 1$

Comment: $m_\varphi$ is an $M_a^\varphi$-module, we have $xy\in  m_\varphi$ for all $x\in m_\varphi, y\in M_a^\varphi$. But how to derive $a=\lim p_ja\in \overline{m_\varphi}$?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. If $p_j\to1$, then $ap_j\to a$.